# kendoui + angularjs + autocomplete show text but set id as value

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, kendo-ui

I'm using [Kendoui's autocomplete](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/autocomplete/index) with angularjs.

I have the following datasource:

```
[{Name:"Albania", Id:"1"},{Name:"Andorra", Id:"2"}]
```

How can I show to the user in the autocomplete the names (albania, andora, etc.) but set the field value to the *id*?

This is what I have tried: [dojo kendoui](http://dojo.telerik.com/ivUye) so I get the whole object now, but can not set the value to id.

```
<script>
  function MyCtrl($scope){
      $scope.countries = [
        {"Name":"Albania", "Id":"1"},
        {"Name":"Andorra", "Id":"2"},
        {"Name":"Armenia", "Id":"3"},
        {"Name":"Austria", "Id":"4"}
      ];
  }
</script>

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input id="i" kendo-auto-complete ng-model="country" k-data-source="countries" data-text-field="Name" />
  <p>
    Your selection: {{ country }}
  </p>
</div>
```

I continue trying to fix, but I'm not there yet:

What i have now is this: [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@dinev/UyOyi)

i thought i can use the select handler and/or the change handler to set the value but keep the text in the autocomplete untouched, but no success.

Comment: Removed a line stating /edit

Answer (score 0):

Haven't really tried using kendo and angularjs, according to [this](http://www.telerik.com/forums/autocomplete-with-k-ng-model-and-datavaluefield-issues), the kendo autocomplete with data primitives true will return array of dataTexfield/olny the string text, the data value field doesn't work. Instead work with the default which is data primitives false that will return the whole selected object. Check this [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/ErEnE) you can get the id by first get the whole object.

Comment: hi. thank you for your answer... no i have this: 

<input id="i" kendo-auto-complete ng-model="country" k-data-source="countries" k-data-text-field="'Name'" k-data-value-field="'Id'" />

on the same dojo link as above. but the value is still set to the Name and not to the Id

Comment: Have a look at my modified answer, soryy i am answering using my tablet. Take a look at the dojo link

Comment: Sorry i see, my mistakes. Aah so hard to modify using tablet.

Comment: no problem :-) tablet keyboards are horror ;-) yes.. your modified dojo is still false... meaning i get still the name as value :-(

Comment: Btw where is the ng-model

Comment: @IsabelleDiez i've update my answer again, now you can see the right one :-)

Comment: dear machun. i'm a little bit confused... wich dojo is the one wich work?

Comment: i guess you mean this dojo: http://dojo.telerik.com/@dinev/AQoMi - if so, the value is still set with the name, not with the id... the name should only shown for the user/select - but the value should be the id

Comment: ok. this dojo http://dojo.telerik.com/@dinev/aziWA is now get the id of the selected value... but i don't know, how to continue and to set this id as value for process the id-value after the formular was submit

Answer (score 0):

i try to continue with fixing the problem. but i'm not finish.

what i have now is this: [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@dinev/UyOyi)

i thought i can use the select handler and/or the change handler to set the value but keep the text in the autocomplete untouched. but i still fail